# subir imagen a laravel ajax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

buenas espero me puedan apoyar con subir una imagen a laravel 5.6

adjunto.

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'archivosimg' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('archivosimg'),
    ],

    'archivos' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('archivos'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],





     if(quien=="formNewTicket"){ var url="newTicket"; var divresul="notificacion";



    var formData = new FormData($("#"+quien+"")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        /*datatype:'json',*/
        data : formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            /*$("#"+divresul+"").html($("#cargador_empresa").html());*/
        },

        //una vez finalizado correctamente
        success: function(data){
            /*$("#"+divresul+"").html(data);
            location.reload(true);*/
            console.log(data);


        },
        //si ha ocurrido un error
        error: function(data){
            alert("ha ocurrido un error") ;
            console.log(data);
        }

    });
```

No entiendo por que me manda  Driver [] is not supported

```
public function newTicket(Request $request){
    $data = Request()->all();
    $usuarioactual=\Auth::user();
    $sede = Seat::find($usuarioactual->D1ID);
    $pabellon = Pavilion::find($data["pabellon"]);
    $piso = Floor::find($data["piso"]);
    $ambiente = Ambient::find($data["ambiente"]);
    $ticket = new Ticket;
    $ticket->C1id=$data["criti"];
    $ticket->P1ID=$data["prov"];
    $ticket->idUser=$data["id"];
    $ticket->K1UBICACION= $sede->D1DESCRIPCION.''.$pabellon->P3DESCRIPCION.''.$piso->P2DESCRIPCION.''.$ambiente->B1DESCRIPCION;
    $ticket->A1ID=$data["origen"];
    $ticket->K1MOTIVO=$data["motivo"];
    $ticket->K1FECHA=date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    $ticket->E1ID=1;
    $ticket->D1ID=$sede->D1ID;
    $ticket->P2ID=$data["piso"];
    $ticket->P3ID=$data["pabellon"];
    $ticket->B1ID=$data["ambiente"];
```

/*Leer apartir de aqui ya lo debugee el error me sale al agregar la linea en donde $r1=Storage::disk ..... .... ...*/

```
    $archivosimg = $request->file('archivosimg');
    if(file_exists($archivosimg)){
        $nombre_original = $archivosimg->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $archivosimg->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $new_name=$sede->D1DESCRIPCION.''.$pabellon->P3DESCRIPCION.''.$piso->P2DESCRIPCION.''.$ambiente->B1DESCRIPCION.".".$extension;
        $input = array('image'=> $archivosimg);
        $ruler = array('image'=> 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif|max:3000');
        $validacion = Validator::make($input,$ruler);
        if ($validacion->fails()) {
            return "imagen rechazado";
        }else{

            $r1=Storage::disk('archivosimg')->put($nombre_original,  \File::get($archivosimg) );

            return $archivosimg.':::::::::::::'.$nombre_original;
        }

    }else{

        return "no se subio imagne";
    }
}
```